# Changing String in Formula VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that I add rows to from time to time.  When I add the row, I copy a row full of formulas that reference other sheets in the workbook (i.e. =Datasheet!A12).  When pasting the formulas, the formulas that don't reference another sheet update to the new row fine but the formulas that reference other sheets do not (i.e. =Datasheet!A12 should become =Datasheet!A13).  So my solution is to loop through the new row and find the formulas with "!" and change the row number.  I'm open to better solutions btw.  Currently, my code is not updating anything.  The "If" statement is always false for some reason.  Here is my code:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim r As Range
Dim cell As Range
Set r = Rows(row_to_insert).Cells

'loop through position sheets and insert blank rows
For i = 1 To 4
    Sheets(i).Select
    Rows(row_to_insert).EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Next i

'loop through position sheets and copy/paste formulas into new rows
For i = 1 To 4
    Sheets(i).Select
    Rows(blank_row_to_use + 1).EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Rows(row_to_insert).EntireRow.Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    r = Rows(row_to_insert)
    For Each cell In r ' loop thorugh passed range relevant cells (i.e. those containing formulas)
        If InStr(cell.Formula, "!") > 0 Then cell = Replace(cell, (row_to_insert - 1), (row_to_insert)) ' if current cell has an explicit sheet reference, then convert its formula to the passed reference type
    Next
Next i
```

row_to_insert is a prompt that lets me pick the row to add and blank_row_to_use is the row with the formulas that I copy.

***Update***
I figured out that my range was setup for the loop to look at cell value and not cell formula.  So for anyone who is looking for a solution to a similar problem, this is what the updated code looks like that works.  Its pretty slow though so if someone has a more elegant solution to my formulas not updating, please let me know.

```
Dim i As Integer
'loop through position sheets and insert blank rows
For i = 1 To 4
    Sheets(i).Select
    Rows(row_to_insert).EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Next i

'loop through position sheets and copy/paste formulas into new rows
For i = 1 To 4
    Sheets(i).Select
    Rows(blank_row_to_use + 1).EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Rows(row_to_insert).EntireRow.Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Dim r As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Set r = Rows(row_to_insert).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
    For Each cell In r ' loop thorugh passed range relevant cells (i.e. those containing formulas)
        If InStr(cell.Formula, "!") > 0 Then cell = Replace(cell.Formula, (row_to_insert - 1), (row_to_insert)) ' if current cell has an explicit sheet reference, then convert its formula to the passed reference type
    Next
Next i
```

Comment: `When pasting the formulas, the formulas that don't reference another sheet update to the new row fine but the formulas that reference other sheets do not` - no, that should not be happening. Excel updates all formulas correctly regardless of sheets. You must be doing something else that prevents the update.

Comment: @GSerg I'm not sure why this happened.  So this code used to work but I added an extra sheet and then it no longer updated the formulas.  Thats why you see the `For Each` part that I had to add.